# How to insert a value into the table or update it if it's already in the table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am setting up a database with two fields, user_id and count, and I want to have an ability to insert this pair of values or increment count by 1 if the record with the same user_id is already in the table.

I have already tried many solutions, for example, INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..., but they don't work for me. It throws an error that says:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ON": syntax error
```

I am running SQLite 3.21.0 on python 3.7.

This is the code I have:

```py
def add_warning(id):
    sql = f"""INSERT INTO warnings (user_id, count) VALUES({id}, 1) ON CONFLICT(user_id) DO UPDATE SET count=count+1"""
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

I expect to get the count value updated when executing the query, but it throws an error when I try to do that.

Comment: *UPSERT syntax was added to SQLite with version 3.24.0* from https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html

Comment: Don't have time to elaborate right now, but the key idea is called an UPSERT... insert or update if there's an existing row.  I think I read/commented on this precise problem just days ago.  Try more searches and I think you'll find related questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `user_id` is the `primary key` of the table you can use [`(INSERT OR) REPLACE`](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-replace-statement/):

```
sql = "REPLACE INTO warnings (user_id, count) VALUES(?, COALESCE((SELECT count + 1 FROM warnings WHERE user_id = ?), 1))"
cursor.execute(sql1, (id, id,))
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/h2s3Trundq1t5nZeoow3An/1).

Answer (score 2):

The upsert syntax you are trying to use is only supported on SQLite versions `3.24.0` or later.  This explains why your code is not working, and here is  a workaround:

```
sql1 = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO warnings (user_id, count) VALUES (?, 0)"
cursor.execute(sql1, (id,))
sql2 = "UPDATE warnings SET count = count + 1 WHERE user_id = ?"
cursor.execute(sql2, (id,))
```

The logic here is to do an initial insert of a user record with a zero count *only* if that user is not already found.  Then, we always update the count by one no matter what.

Comment: @forpas The initial insert, if it happens, would insert a count of zero.  So, we still want that update to happen _afterwards_, to bring the initial count up from zero to one.

Comment: I did not notice the `0` in the INSERT statement, but I think that first doing the UPDATE and then INSERT with `1` is better since it will affect the row only once.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this. 
This works on SQL Server but I haven't tried this on SQLite

```
sql = "IF EXISTS (select user_id FROM warnings WHERE user_id={0}) " + \
"BEGIN " + \
"UPDATE warnings SET count = count + 1  WHERE user_id={0} " + \
"END " + \
"ELSE " + \
"INSERT INTO warnings (user_id, count) VALUES ({0}, 0 )".format(id)
```